# Counting how many words in datagridview column when the button is clicked

Tags: vb.net, gridview, datagridview

In my form I have a button and 2 labels (and of course, a datagridview) in my form. What I want to accomplish is when the user clicks the button, it'll show how many certain text are in the datagridview column.

I have a column named "Domestic_Animals" and there are two separate panels, one for dog and one for cat. When the user clicks the "Count How Many Dogs in the GridView" button, it'll show how many "dogs" text are in the gridview. Same with the "Cats" button.

```
/*DOMESTIC_ANIMALS/
Dog
Cat
Cat
Cat
Dog

<btnDogs> (the user clicks this) : Label1.Text = 2
<btnCats< (the user clicks this):  Label2.Text = 3
```

For further information, my datagridview is data bounded. So the user may add more dogs and cats in an INSERT query. So the answer should not be always '2' for dogs or '3' for cats but instead that the code really counts how many cats word or dogs word are in the datagridview.

Any suggestion will help me.

**EDIT:** *The answer is in the bottom.*

Comment: please show what you have tried...

Comment: Sorry, I cocked up the first answer as I hadn't realised that you couldn't access the datagridview datasource via linq easily. I've updated my answer if that helps...

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the back end data (e.g. with Entity Framework) you could use a linq query

```
    Dim arr = {"Dog", "Cat", "Cat", "Cat", "Dog"}
    Dim countDogs = arr.Where(Function(f) f = "Dog").Count
    Dim countCats = arr.Where(Function(f) f = "Cat").Count
```

Just replace arr with the relevant collection in your EF context.

If not, I don;t think you can access the back end datasource of the dgv with linq as it's not strongly typed, so you would have to do something like this, assuming that the entry you are searching for is in the first column:

```
    Function CountAnimal(strToLookFor as String) as Integer
            Dim row As DataGridViewRow
            Dim count As Integer = 0

            For lp = 0 To PortfoliosGrid.Rows.Count - 1
                If PortfoliosGrid.Rows(lp).Cells(0).Value = strToLookFor Then
                    count += 1
                End If
            Next

            Return count
     End Function
```

Comment: And swap out PortfoliosGrid for the name of your datagridview (it looks like it's DataGridView1 from your code)

Comment: OK. I will try this code. I am not going to up-vote, accept this an answer 'till I play around with your code.

Answer (score 0):

The following code solved my problem:

```
Dim x As Integer = 16

lblRows2.Text = (From Rows In DataGridView1.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)() Where Not Rows.IsNewRow AndAlso Rows.Cells(x).Value.ToString = "Dog").Count
```

This code means that the label will count how many the word "Dog" are in the column.